# Extract data from ternary contour image file

Tags: image, file, extract, contour, ternary

[image]

I just have the image above, and I want to extract data from it.
I tried plot Digitizer, but it cannot deal with the contour.
How can I extract the data from the ternary contour of the image file?

Other examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you want to extract exactly, please? And how will the output look? Will it be a CSV? Or a number? Or a colour? Or an SVG file?

Comment: I want to extract data-points including compositions and contour data, such as protein a %, lactose b %, fat c %, and benefit z(colorbar) values. So it will be 4 columns of protein, lactose, fat, and benefit. Every row will have (a, b, c, z) data, technically I mean the matrix. I expect a CSV file then.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to get the concept. How many rows will there be - I'm trying to understand how often and where the points in the triangle need to be sampled. And second question, presumably you have many plots to scan, so are the triangle vertices always the same colour and always in the same place, or must they be located, and is the colour-scale thing at top-left always the same colour with the same range of values? -14..14?

Comment: You exactly pointed out the tricky things. I want to extract the points as much as possible where the contour is available. At least 1 % intervals between (a, b, c) points will be good. For example, the contour in the given figure is available in all compositions, so targeted rows would be such as (1%, 98%, 1%), (1%, 97%, 2%), ..., (2%, 97%, 1%), (2%, 96%, 2%)..., (98%, 1%, 1%). Otherwise, the number of rows can be changed as much as the contour surrounds. Most plots to scan have contours in the partial compositions. And they can have different color ranges. I put some other example figures.